# ERROR: Unresolved Reference : context in LayoutInflater(context)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to kotlin and android studio development. I am trying to make a simple To Do List app which has a "newTask" button to add a new task. In the main layout kotlin file, I added the following commands for the button:

```
 newTask.setOnClickListener{
            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this,)
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogue_dashboard, null)
            val toDoName = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_todo)
            dialog.setView(view)            
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Add"){ _: DialogInterface, _ : Int ->
                if(toDoName.text.isNotEmpty()){
                    val toDo = ToDo()
                    toDo.name = toDoName.text.toString()
                    dbHandller.addToDo(toDo)
                }
            }
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->

            }
            dialog.show()
        }
```

I am also using recycler view for it all to work and I am in middle of creating the adapter for recycler view:

```
class DashboardAdapter(context: Context,val list: MutableList<ToDo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
        class ViewHolder(v : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){
            val toDoName : TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_todo_name)
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_child_layout)

        }
```

The error that has popped is in context. When I hover mouse over it the error says "Unresolved reference:context". I have no idea how to solve it and nothing in google seems to show up for the problem. Show context actions doesn't seem to help as it does nothing and context with red color is still there.

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Comment: you should mark the answer as accepted if it worked! It lets other people know you don't need help anymore

Answer (score 1):

change the class declaration to this:

```
class DashboardAdapter(val context: Context, ...
```